# Why is looping over range() in Python faster than using a while loop?

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking

The other day I was doing some Python benchmarking and I came across something interesting.  Below are two loops that do more or less the same thing.  Loop 1 takes about twice as long as loop 2 to execute.

Loop 1:

```py
i = 0
while i < 100000000:
    i += 1
```

Loop 2:

```py
for n in range(0,100000000):
    pass
```

Why is the first loop so much slower?  I know it's a trivial example but it's piqued my interest.  Is there something special about the range() function that makes it more efficient than incrementing a variable the same way?

Comment: On 3.8 I am finding that the difference is more like a factor of 3.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

see the disassembly of python byte code, you may get a more concrete idea

use while loop:

```
1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
            3 STORE_NAME               0 (i)

2           6 SETUP_LOOP              28 (to 37)
      >>    9 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)              # <-
           12 LOAD_CONST               1 (100000000)      # <-
           15 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)              # <-
           18 JUMP_IF_FALSE           14 (to 35)          # <-
           21 POP_TOP                                     # <-

3          22 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)              # <-
           25 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)              # <-
           28 INPLACE_ADD                                 # <-
           29 STORE_NAME               0 (i)              # <-
           32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9                  # <-
      >>   35 POP_TOP
           36 POP_BLOCK
```

The loop body has 10 op

use range:

```
1           0 SETUP_LOOP              23 (to 26)
            3 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
            6 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
            9 LOAD_CONST               1 (100000000)
           12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
           15 GET_ITER
      >>   16 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 25)        # <-
           19 STORE_NAME               1 (n)            # <-

2          22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16                # <-
      >>   25 POP_BLOCK
      >>   26 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
           29 RETURN_VALUE
```

The loop body has 3 op

The time to run C code is much shorter than intepretor and can be ignored.

Answer (score 41):

`range()` is implemented in C, whereas `i += 1` is interpreted.

Using `xrange()` could make it even faster for large numbers. Starting with Python 3.0 `range()` is the same as previously `xrange()`.

Answer (score 21):

It must be said that there is a lot of object creation and destruction going on with the while loop.

```
i += 1
```

is the same as:

```
i = i + 1
```

But because Python ints are immutable, it doesn't modify the existing object; rather it creates a brand new object with a new value. It's basically:

```
i = new int(i + 1)   # Using C++ or Java-ish syntax
```

The garbage collector will also have a large amount of cleanup to do.
"Object creation is expensive".

Update:
Interesting. Now using 3.11, `for` is actually slower than `while` for low iteration counts:

| Iterations | while loop | for loop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 109 |
| 5 | 23 | 26 |
| 10 | 18 | 16 |
| 1_000 | 18 | 9.2 |
| 1_000_000 | 18 | 11 |

(ns/iteration, Win 10, CPython 3.11.4, ipython %timeit)

Both are quite stable ns/iteration over 100.

Comment: Object creation and GC doesn't, as far as I can tell, meaningfully impact on the results. In particular, the speed advantage for the `for` loop is at least as big for smaller iteration counts, where all the necessary objects will be interned.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if interning happens for large numbers? Anyway, I've added an updated table (above as can't do table md in comments) with some observations.

Comment: Timing only the loop overhead for very low iteration counts is going to be relatively tricky/unreliable, even with all the precautions `timeit` takes. It's also, pretty much definitionally, not important for overall program performance.

Comment: Agreed. Interested the `dis` is different in 3.11 to the original post.

Comment: The bytecode format can potentially change with each minor version, and sometimes does.

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer here is a little more subtle than the other answers suggest, though the gist of it is correct: **the for loop is faster because more of the operations happen in C and less in Python**.

More specifically, in the for loop case, two things happen in C that in the while loop are handled in Python:

1. In the while loop, the comparison `i < 100000000` is executed in Python, whereas in the for loop, the job is passed to the iterator of `range(100000000)`, which internally does the iteration (and hence bounds check) in C.
2. In the while loop, the loop update `i += 1` happens in Python, whereas in the for loop again the iterator of `range(100000000)`, written in C, does the `i+=1` (or `++i`).

We can see that it is a combination of both of these things that makes the for loop faster by manually adding them back to see the difference.

```
import timeit

N = 100000000


def while_loop():
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        i += 1


def for_loop_pure():
    for i in range(N):
        pass


def for_loop_with_increment():
    for i in range(N):
        i += 1


def for_loop_with_test():
    for i in range(N):
        if i < N: pass


def for_loop_with_increment_and_test():
    for i in range(N):
        if i < N: pass
        i += 1


def main():
    print('while loop\t\t', timeit.timeit(while_loop, number=1))
    print('for pure\t\t', timeit.timeit(for_loop_pure, number=1))
    print('for inc\t\t\t', timeit.timeit(for_loop_with_increment, number=1))
    print('for test\t\t', timeit.timeit(for_loop_with_test, number=1))
    print('for inc+test\t', timeit.timeit(for_loop_with_increment_and_test, number=1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried this both with the number 100000000 a literal constant and with it being a variable `N` as would be more typical.

```
# inline constant N
while loop      3.5131139
for pure        1.3211338000000001
for inc         3.5477727000000003
for test        2.5209639
for inc+test    4.697028999999999

# variable N
while loop      4.1298240999999996
for pure        1.3526357999999998
for inc         3.6060175
for test        3.1093069
for inc+test    5.4753364
```

As you can see, in both cases, the `while` time is very close to the difference of `for inc+test` and `for pure`. Note also that in the case where we use the `N` variable, the `while` has an additional slowdown to repeatedly lookup the value of `N`, but the `for` does not.

It's really crazy that such trivial modifications can result in over **3x code speedup**, but that's Python for you. And don't even get me started on when you can use a builtin over a loop at all....

Answer (score 4):

Because you are running more often in code written in C in the interpretor.  i.e. i+=1 is in Python, so slow (comparatively), whereas range(0,...) is one C call the for loop will execute mostly in C too.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Python's built in method calls are run as C code. Code that has to be interpreted is much slower. In terms of memory efficiency and execution speed the difference is gigantic. The python internals have been optimized to the extreme, and it's best to take advantage of those optimizations.