# How do I disassemble a Python script?

Tags: python, debugging, reverse-engineering

Earlier today, I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop) about the way Python handles certain kinds of loops.  One of the answers contained disassembled versions of my examples.

I'd like to know more.  How can I disassemble my own Python code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) module:

```
def myfunc(alist):
    return len(alist)

>>> dis.dis(myfunc)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (alist)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides using `dis` as module, you can also run it as command line tool

For example, on windows you can run:

```
c:\Python25\Lib\dis.py test.py
```

And it will output the disassembed result to console.

Comment: Another way to use it: "python -m dis test.py"

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dis` module from the Python standard library (`import dis` e.g. in an interactive interpreter, then `dis.dis` any function you care about!-).