# Python meaning of variables followed by comma and newline

Tags: python, newline

I saw some weird printout when I had a variable followed by a comma and I was wondering what the Python interpreter really does when it encounters it.

```
def new_func():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    return x,y

x = 0
x,
y = new_func()

print(x,y)
```

Output: `0 (1,2)`

So what exactly was printed? How did Python handle `x,↵`? What can I use this for?

Comment: That is a `tuple` literal

Comment: If you want to know what something does in Python, disassembling it could be useful. See [How do I disassemble a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869586/4518341)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, in Python **the comma makes something a tuple.**
The newline does not have any effect.

E.g. `i = 1`, is equivalent to `i = (1,)`

General Example:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1,
(1,)
```

**Your case:**

```
>>> x = 0

>>> type(x)
int

>>> x,
(0,) # this is just the printed version of x as tuple

>>> x = x, # actual assignment to tuple

>>> type(x)
tuple
```

Comment: So in other words, it wrapped x in a tuple, then discarded it; basically having no effect.

Comment: no you did not wrap. you just printed the tuple version of it. to wrap you need `i = 1`, `i = i,` . Then i becomes a tuple. see my answer

Comment: I'm not the OP. They seem to be asking what `x,` on its own line does. "How did Python handle `x,↵`".

Comment: yes. the OP just printed the tuple version of it by typing `x,`

Comment: So it seems that the line `y = new_func()` assigns a tuple since it did not find a second variable to unpack to. so `y` is now a tuple of `new_func()`'s `x,y` return. The `x,` was just an unassigned tuple. So the statement `print(x,y)` ends up printing x-->`0` (which was globally assigned) and then y-->`(1,2)`.