# compute crc of file in python

Tags: python, hash, crc

I want to calculate the [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) of file and get output like: `E45A12AC`. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import os, sys
import zlib

def crc(fileName):
    fd = open(fileName,"rb")
    content = fd.readlines()
    fd.close()
    for eachLine in content:
        zlib.crc32(eachLine)

for eachFile in sys.argv[1:]:
    crc(eachFile)
```

This calculates the CRC for each line, but its output (e.g. `-1767935985`) is not what I want.

Hashlib works the way I want, but it computes the md5:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
for line in open('data.txt', 'rb'):
    m.update(line)
print m.hexdigest()
```

Is it possible to get something similar using `zlib.crc32`?

Answer (score 35):

A little more compact and optimized code

```
def crc(fileName):
    prev = 0
    for eachLine in open(fileName,"rb"):
        prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
    return "%X"%(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

PS2: Old PS is deprecated - therefore deleted -, because of the suggestion in the comment. Thank you. I don't get, how I missed this, but it was really good.

Comment: If you set `prev` to 0 instead then you don't need to worry about an exception.

Comment: Something even faster which does result in the same output: def crc(filename): return "%X"%(zlib.crc32(open(filename,"rb").read()) & 0xFFFFFFFF) This reads the whole file into memory and calculates the CRC32.  Granted, the bigger the file the more memory the program needs; depends on the trade-off you want, memory for speed, or speed for memory.

Comment: A way to speed up the calculation considerably (factor 2--3) while keeping the memory usage low is to read fixed size chunks instead of reading "lines" from the binary file. Added a separate answer for this.

Answer (score 22):

A modified version of kobor42's answer, with performance improved by a factor 2-3 by reading fixed size chunks instead of "lines":

```
import zlib

def crc32(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as fh:
        hash = 0
        while True:
            s = fh.read(65536)
            if not s:
                break
            hash = zlib.crc32(s, hash)
        return "%08X" % (hash & 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

Also includes leading zeroes in the returned string.

Answer (score 15):

*hashlib*-compatible interface for CRC-32 support:

```
import zlib

class crc32(object):
    name = 'crc32'
    digest_size = 4
    block_size = 1

    def __init__(self, arg=''):
        self.__digest = 0
        self.update(arg)

    def copy(self):
        copy = super(self.__class__, self).__new__(self.__class__)
        copy.__digest = self.__digest
        return copy

    def digest(self):
        return self.__digest

    def hexdigest(self):
        return '{:08x}'.format(self.__digest)

    def update(self, arg):
        self.__digest = zlib.crc32(arg, self.__digest) & 0xffffffff

# Now you can define hashlib.crc32 = crc32
import hashlib
hashlib.crc32 = crc32

# Python > 2.7: hashlib.algorithms += ('crc32',)
# Python > 3.2: hashlib.algorithms_available.add('crc32')
```

Answer (score 9):

To show any integer's lowest 32 bits as 8 hexadecimal digits, without sign, you can "mask" the value by bit-and'ing it with a mask made of 32 bits all at value 1, then apply formatting.  I.e.:

```
>>> x = -1767935985
>>> format(x & 0xFFFFFFFF, '08x')
'969f700f'
```

It's quite irrelevant whether the integer you are thus formatting comes from `zlib.crc32` or any other computation whatsoever.

Comment: Good point re: formatting, but it looks like his code also doesn't compute what he wants it to. There are really two problems here: 1) Compute the CRC of a file. 2) Display the CRC value as hex.

Comment: Not only that, but format is slower than "%X"%(x & 0xFFFFFFFF), provided kobor24's answer.  But it was nice to see another way to do it, I've never used format before.

Answer (score 9):

Python 3.8+ (using the walrus operator):

```
import zlib

def crc32(filename, chunksize=65536):
    """Compute the CRC-32 checksum of the contents of the given filename"""
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        checksum = 0
        while (chunk := f.read(chunksize)) :
            checksum = zlib.crc32(chunk, checksum)
        return checksum
```

`chunksize` is how many bytes to read from the file at a time. You will get the same CRC for the same file no matter what you set `chunksize` to (it has to be `> 0`), but setting it too low might make your code slow, too high might use too much memory.

The result is a 32 bit integer. The CRC-32 checksum of an empty file is `0`.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited to include Altren's solution below.**

A modified and more compact version of CrouZ's answer, with a slightly improved performance, using a for loop and file buffering:

```
def forLoopCrc(fpath):
    """With for loop and buffer."""
    crc = 0
    with open(fpath, 'rb', 65536) as ins:
        for x in range(int((os.stat(fpath).st_size / 65536)) + 1):
            crc = zlib.crc32(ins.read(65536), crc)
    return '%08X' % (crc & 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

Results, in a 6700k, HDD:

(Note: Retested multiple times and it was consistently faster.)

```
Warming up the machine...
Finished.

Beginning tests...
File size: 90288KB
Test cycles: 500

With for loop and buffer.
Result 45.24728019630359 

CrouZ solution
Result 45.433838356097894 

kobor42 solution
Result 104.16215688703986 

Altren solution
Result 101.7247863946586
```

Tested in Python 3.6.4 x64 using the script below:

```
import os, timeit, zlib, random, binascii

def forLoopCrc(fpath):
    """With for loop and buffer."""
    crc = 0
    with open(fpath, 'rb', 65536) as ins:
        for x in range(int((os.stat(fpath).st_size / 65536)) + 1):
            crc = zlib.crc32(ins.read(65536), crc)
    return '%08X' % (crc & 0xFFFFFFFF)

def crc32(fileName):
    """CrouZ solution"""
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as fh:
        hash = 0
        while True:
            s = fh.read(65536)
            if not s:
                break
            hash = zlib.crc32(s, hash)
        return "%08X" % (hash & 0xFFFFFFFF)

def crc(fileName):
    """kobor42 solution"""
    prev = 0
    for eachLine in open(fileName,"rb"):
        prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
    return "%X"%(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF)

def crc32altren(filename):
    """Altren solution"""
    buf = open(filename,'rb').read()
    hash = binascii.crc32(buf) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    return "%08X" % hash

fpath = r'D:\test\test.dat'
tests = {forLoopCrc: 'With for loop and buffer.', 
     crc32: 'CrouZ solution', crc: 'kobor42 solution',
         crc32altren: 'Altren solution'}
count = 500

# CPU, HDD warmup
randomItm = [x for x in tests.keys()]
random.shuffle(randomItm)
print('\nWarming up the machine...')
for c in range(count):
    randomItm[0](fpath)
print('Finished.\n')

# Begin test
print('Beginning tests...\nFile size: %dKB\nTest cycles: %d\n' % (
    os.stat(fpath).st_size/1024, count))
for x in tests:
    print(tests[x])
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    for c in range(count):
        x(fpath)
    print('Result', timeit.default_timer() - start_time, '\n')
```

It is faster because **for** loops are faster than **while** loops (sources: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop) and [here](https://www.blog.duomly.com/loops-in-python-comparison-and-performance/)).

Answer (score 2):

Merge the above 2 codes as below:

```
try:
    fd = open(decompressedFile,"rb")
except IOError:
    logging.error("Unable to open the file in readmode:" + decompressedFile)
    return 4
eachLine = fd.readline()
prev = 0
while eachLine:
    prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
    eachLine = fd.readline()
fd.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is faster and more compact way to compute CRC using binascii:

```
import binascii

def crc32(filename):
    buf = open(filename,'rb').read()
    hash = binascii.crc32(buf) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    return "%08X" % hash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 for getting out like [ERD45FTR]. And zlib.crc32 provides update options.

```
import os, sys
import zlib
import base64
```

def crc(fileName):
  fd = open(fileName,"rb")
  content = fd.readlines()
  fd.close()
  prev = None
  for eachLine in content:
   if not prev:
     prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine)
   else:
     prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
  return prev

for eachFile in sys.argv[1:]:
  print base64.b64encode(str(crc(eachFile)))

Comment: Thanks for syntax.
I get LTc3NzI0ODI2, but i want E45A12AC (8 digits). Tried base32, base16.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
import os, sys
import zlib

def crc(fileName, excludeLine="", includeLine=""):
  try:
        fd = open(fileName,"rb")
  except IOError:
        print "Unable to open the file in readmode:", filename
        return
  eachLine = fd.readline()
  prev = None
  while eachLine:
      if excludeLine and eachLine.startswith(excludeLine):
            continue   
      if not prev:
        prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine)
      else:
        prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
      eachLine = fd.readline()
  fd.close()    
  return format(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF, '08x') #returns 8 digits crc

for eachFile in sys.argv[1:]:
    print crc(eachFile)
```

don't realy know for what is (excludeLine="", includeLine="")...

Comment: I know this is ancient, but I'll explain anyway. I gave you a downvote because I don't think it's useful to post code that you don't understand.