# Python network convert byte

Tags: python, networking, encoding, byte, utf-16le

I'm trying to implement a CRC verification on a network based protocol.
CRC calculation is done via the PyCRC lib.

PyCRC will generate a checksum for the given packet and return a result like this:
CB3D9FD1

When I try to send it on the wire, somehow python modify my string and convert it in ascii to Hex, example:

```
Crc = "CB3D9FD1"
...
buffer = "\x41\x42\x43\x44"+crc
...
s.send(buffer)
```

On the wire I will see that:

```
\x41\x42\x43\x44***\x43\x42\x33\x44\x39\x46\x44\x31***
```

Instead of:

```
 \x41\x42\x43\x44***\xCB\x3D\x9F\xD1***
```

Any ways to solve this issue easily ?

Thanks !

Comment: You'll need to provide some additional hint as to what you're doing.  Code helps.  The smallest code that demonstrates the problem is ideal.  Feel free to create a short demo script that fails, and **update** your question with it.  Python is not doing anything bad; your script has some small mistake in it.

Comment: Why are you going this route?  Look at this answer for an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742866/compute-crc-of-file-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, don't convert your CRC to ASCII. Keep it in hex and then pack it into a byte string using [struct.pack](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=struct.pack&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html&ei=7bz8Ts6PMYfnggffmbWUAg&usg=AFQjCNEwS2UiygucVlDx_9qbMzNwr8ufXA&sig2=iFeD23P2q6_A02YNDd0J6Q)::

```
buffer += struct.pack("L", crc)
```

Comment: Yup I tried that before, only issue is struct return this : ***struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer***

Comment: I'd also recommend to use the exclamation mark (`'!L'`) to ensure network byte order (probably needed).

Comment: @n00bz0r make sure your crc is an integer, perhaps parse it first: int(crc, 16).

Comment: crc must be numeric value, not a string. try `crc=0xCB3D9FD1` and `buffer += struct.pack("I", crc)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have converted the CRC to a string containing "CB3D9FD1", then the correct byte sequence is 0x43 0x42 0x33 0x44 0x39 0x46 0x44 0x31. Don't convert the cry into a string or parse the string as a hex (two characters to each byte).

Answer (score 0):

By assigning it this way: `crc = "CB3D9FD1"` you are saying make var crc an 8 byte string. As @Bashwork says you need to convert it from hex string to numeric or keep it numeric. Assign it with **0x** like this to get a numeric value: `crc=0xCB3D9FD1`.

pack("L",x) means I am giving you x which is(must be) an **integer** and I want you to pack it as an **unsigned long**.
You get **"struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer"** because you are passing pack("L",...) a string "CB3D9FD1".

RTFM what "L" and "I" and other args mean: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Pack the CRC as long integer works: and you get 0s padding out to 64bits (on my PC. YMMV)

```
>>> from struct import pack
>>> crc=0xcb3d9fd1
>>> repr(crc)
'3409813457'
>>> pack("L", crc)
'\xd1\x9f=\xcb\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> print crc
3409813457
```

Maybe you want to use pack("I",...): to get 32bits

```
>>> pack("I",crc)
'\xd1\x9f=\xcb'
```

Fail if try to pack a CRC string with pack("L",...):

```
>>> crc = "CB3D9FD1"
>>> repr(crc)
"'CB3D9FD1'"
>>> pack("L", crc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer
```