# Confused with answer about best/worst case time for Python function

Tags: python, performance, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

This is a short problem from edx's course Introduction to Computer Science and Programming using Python.

```
def program1(x):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        total += i

    while x > 0:
        x -= 1
        total += x

    return total
```

**Question :** What is the number of steps it will take to run Program 1 in the best case? Express your answer in terms of n, the size of the input x

**Answer** : Best case : 3003   and   Worst Case : 5n+3003

I am confused with the answer 3003 because according to me the problem's best case would be if x =-1 and other statements execute which have a constant amount of time .hence 
statement

```
total =0   // takes a constant amount of time 1

for i in range(1000):
    total += i        // takes 1000*1 amount of time


return total   // takes constant of time 1
```

Hence the answer should be 1000+2=1002

Any  help with proper explanation will be highly appreciated ..

Comment: Can you link to that course?

Comment: @TimPietzcker https://www.edx.org/course/mitx/mitx-6-00-1x-introduction-computer-1841

Comment: Your code is not indented correctly and you don't explain the question properly. According to your code worse case is when x -> infinite. and best case is when x < 1. The sum 3003 is not depended on x at all! The link to the course is not helpful - but a link to the original question will be.

Comment: @alfasin question edited ..and i have already copied the question from the course dashboard..

Comment: and *everything* I wrote before still applies...

Comment: It is just a conjecture of mine, somebody please correct me if I am wrong: You summed up to 1002 which should be 1003 because the condition `x > 0:` will be executed at-least once. Also, shorthand += is `total = total + i;` which is an assignment+addition so multiply 1000 with 2 instead of 1.

Comment: yeah infact 1003 ..thanks for the correction @AbdulFatir

Comment: @alfasin Question edited with snapshot..please see to it..

Comment: okay so now the indent part has been taken care of. What about the rest ?

Comment: it would be better if we have right `title` for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the key to understanding the answer is that the line `for i in range(1000):` is doing *two* things [*ed: see update below*] each time through the loop that you neglected to count:  first, it is incrementing the variable `i` and second, it is checking it against the maximum value (1000) to see if the loop is finished.  So each pass through the loop should count as 3 operations.

Finally, even if the loop is skipped, it still takes one operation to decide to do this, that is to check `x` against `0` in the line:  `while x > 0:`.

This is how it would be accounted in the best case:

```
def program1(x):
    total = 0                  // counts as 1
    for i in range(1000):      // counts as 2 * 1000
        total += i             // counts as 1 * 1000

    while x > 0:               // counts as 1 + N  (note: so when x <= 0, still counts as 1)
        x -= 1
        total += x

    return total               // counts as 1
```

...which adds up to 3003.

---

**Update:**

Given that the *worst* case answer provided to you is `5n + 3003`, I must modify my answer.

That means that the `-=` and `+=` operations within the while loop must be being counted as two separate operations (the increment or decrement and the assignment).  If so, then the `+=` operation within the for loop must also count as 2 operations.  And if that is the case, the only way to make the numbers agree with the provided answer is if the accounting is like this:

```
def program1(x):
    total = 0                  // counts as 1
    for i in range(1000):      // counts as 1 * 1000
        total += i             // counts as 2 * 1000

    while x > 0:               // counts as 1 + N
        x -= 1                 // counts as 2 * N
        total += x             // counts as 2 * N

    return total               // counts as 1
```

I personally disagree with counting the `+=` and `-=` as two things, in the abstract sense, because I know that they can be done as a single operation in assembly (assuming all values are in registers), but *in Python* they are actually two operations.  (See the 4th answer in the link below for more on this.)

To accept this accounting, you must also accept that the line `for i in range(1000):` only counts as *one* operation each time through the loop.  Upon realizing that I was wrong above, I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop) which helps with understanding that.  Basically, this is because the upper bound as well as the iterated elements themselves of the loop are fixed.

Comment: You considered assignment and condition testing as 2 seperate operations inside the for loop ..so according to me including i=1,i<1000,i+=1 these are 3 separate operations and takes a constant amount of time..Shouldn't the answer be 1000*4+3=4003? Correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: @DiljitPR The *initialization* of `i` does not need to happen 1000 times.  And the first time through the loop, instead of *incrementing* `i`, the value is just initialized.  [Note:   depending on the implementation, there *might* be a need for an additional step for the *last* time through the loop (if, for example, `i` gets incremented to 1001 immediately prior to exiting the loop), which could lead to a count of 3004 instead of 3003, but I *think* in Python, when iterating over a range, this isn't necessary.]

Comment: @DiljitPR Although I consider my original explanation "correct", I am going to modify my answer after considering the *worst* case (which I know you didn't ask about but is inconsistent with the logic I used for my answer).

Comment: This helps ..If possible can u try and make an explanation for the worst case scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57467/discussion-between-diljit-pr-and-turix).

Comment: Heres the answer :In the best case scenario, x is less than or equal to 0. We first execute the assignment total = 0 for one step. Next we execute the for i in range(1000) loop. This loop is executed 1000 times and has three steps (one for the assignment of i each time through the loop, as well as two for the += operation) on each iteration. We next check if x > 0 - it is not so we do not enter the loop. Adding one more step for the return statement, in the best case we execute 1 + 3*1000 + 1 + 1 = 3003 steps.

Comment: @DiljitPR Thanks. I think that agrees with my update. Did you not have access to that prior to posting your question?