# Incorrect implementation of insertion sort, or incorrect understanding of time complexity?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have been writing a few python scripts to test and time various common algorithms, purely for my own edification. I'm sure there are already resources out there that have done this, but I find it helpful to write them myself.

I have written a script that implements bubble, selection, and insertion sort, and for each one it runs 10 iterations of varying array sizes, as well as best/worst/average array order cases.

In most cases I am seeing what I expected, for instance selection sort always takes the same time regardless of the order of the array, and bubble sort performs abysmal as expected. I also see that insertion sort's performance does improve as the order of the given array improves, however I am confused by the comparison of selection and insertion.

I am aware that both algorithms have a worst-case time complexity of O(n^2), and that the average time complexity for insertion sort is better than selection sort, but I am seeing that in a lot of cases, insertion sort is performing worse than selection sort, which seems incorrect to me. I would expect the two to perform the same in the worst-case, and that insertion sort would perform better when not worst-case. Am I misunderstanding how to interpret these results, or have I made an error in my implementation of the two algorithms?

Here is my script:

```
import random
import time
import sys
from enum import Enum

class Case(Enum):
    BEST = 1
    WORST = 2
    AVERAGE = 3

def bubble_sort(arr):
    sorted = False
    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(0, len(arr)):
            # n
            if i + 1 < len(arr) and arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:
                scratch = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
                arr[i + 1] = scratch
                sorted = False
    return arr

def selection_sort(arr):
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        # n
        min_index = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            # n
            if arr[j] < arr[min_index]:
                min_index = j
        scratch = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[min_index]
        arr[min_index] = scratch
    return arr

def insertion_sort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        # n
        index = i
        while index > 0 and arr[index - 1] > arr[index]:
            # worst case n, best case 1
            scratch = arr[index]
            arr[index] = arr[index - 1]
            arr[index - 1] = scratch
            index -= 1
    return arr

TOTAL_RUNS = 10

def verify(algorithm, name):

    # first let's test that it actually sorts correctly
    arr = list(range(1, 20))
    random.shuffle(arr)
    arr = algorithm(arr)
    for i in range(0, len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:
            raise Exception("NOT SORTED!")

    print("timing " + name + " sort...")

    def time_the_algorithm(algorithm, case):
        total = 0
        min = sys.maxsize
        max = 0

        sizes = [1000,5000,10000]

        for size in sizes:
            for i in range(0, TOTAL_RUNS):

                arr = list(range(1, size))
                if case == Case.WORST:
                    # for worst case, reverse entire array
                    arr = list(reversed(arr))
                elif case == Case.AVERAGE:
                    # average case, random order
                    random.shuffle(arr)

                start = time.time()
                arr = algorithm(arr)
                end = time.time()

                elapsed = end - start
                total += elapsed
                if elapsed > max:
                    max = elapsed
                if elapsed <= min:
                    min = elapsed

            print(name + ", n={0:} - ".format(size) + str(case) + ": avg {0:.2f}s, min {1:.2f}s, max {2:.2f}s".format(total/TOTAL_RUNS, min, max))

    # worst case
    time_the_algorithm(algorithm, Case.WORST)
    # avg case
    time_the_algorithm(algorithm, Case.AVERAGE)
    # best case
    time_the_algorithm(algorithm, Case.BEST)


verify(insertion_sort, "insertion")
verify(selection_sort, "selection")
verify(bubble_sort, "bubble")
```

And here is my output:

```
timing insertion sort...
insertion, n=1000 - Case.WORST: avg 0.06s, min 0.06s, max 0.06s
insertion, n=5000 - Case.WORST: avg 1.42s, min 0.06s, max 1.46s
insertion, n=10000 - Case.WORST: avg 6.90s, min 0.06s, max 5.70s
insertion, n=1000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.03s, min 0.03s, max 0.03s
insertion, n=5000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.71s, min 0.03s, max 0.70s
insertion, n=10000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 3.44s, min 0.03s, max 2.76s
insertion, n=1000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.00s, min 0.00s, max 0.00s
insertion, n=5000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.00s, min 0.00s, max 0.00s
insertion, n=10000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.00s, min 0.00s, max 0.00s
timing selection sort...
selection, n=1000 - Case.WORST: avg 0.02s, min 0.02s, max 0.02s
selection, n=5000 - Case.WORST: avg 0.43s, min 0.02s, max 0.43s
selection, n=10000 - Case.WORST: avg 2.17s, min 0.02s, max 1.84s
selection, n=1000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.01s, min 0.01s, max 0.02s
selection, n=5000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.43s, min 0.01s, max 0.44s
selection, n=10000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 2.30s, min 0.01s, max 1.93s
selection, n=1000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.01s, min 0.01s, max 0.02s
selection, n=5000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.42s, min 0.01s, max 0.41s
selection, n=10000 - Case.BEST: avg 2.26s, min 0.01s, max 1.92s
timing bubble sort...
bubble, n=1000 - Case.WORST: avg 0.11s, min 0.11s, max 0.11s
bubble, n=5000 - Case.WORST: avg 3.15s, min 0.11s, max 3.24s
bubble, n=10000 - Case.WORST: avg 15.09s, min 0.11s, max 13.66s
bubble, n=1000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.09s, min 0.09s, max 0.10s
bubble, n=5000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 2.62s, min 0.09s, max 2.63s
bubble, n=10000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 12.53s, min 0.09s, max 10.90s
bubble, n=1000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.00s, min 0.00s, max 0.00s
bubble, n=5000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.00s, min 0.00s, max 0.00s
bubble, n=10000 - Case.BEST: avg 0.00s, min 0.00s, max 0.00s
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have taken the advice of @asaf-rosemarin and tried to replace the while loop with a for-loop to see if that will make the timing more even, but it did not seem to impact the performance at all

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        # n
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):
            # worst case n, best case 1
            if arr[j - 1] > arr[j]:
                scratch = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1]
                arr[j - 1] = scratch
            else:
                break
    return arr
```

output:

```
timing insertion sort...
insertion, n=1000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.03s, min 0.03s, max 0.03s
insertion, n=5000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.72s, min 0.03s, max 0.74s
insertion, n=10000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 3.61s, min 0.03s, max 3.13s
timing selection sort...
selection, n=1000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.02s, min 0.02s, max 0.02s
selection, n=5000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.47s, min 0.02s, max 0.51s
selection, n=10000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 2.52s, min 0.02s, max 2.17s
timing bubble sort...
bubble, n=1000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 0.10s, min 0.09s, max 0.10s
bubble, n=5000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 2.56s, min 0.09s, max 2.50s
bubble, n=10000 - Case.AVERAGE: avg 12.31s, min 0.09s, max 10.34s
```

Comment: That the change from `while` to `for ... in range` didn't impact performance tells you that there is no appreciable difference in the performance of those two looping constructs.

Comment: In this question, it was demonstrated that while loops can be slower due to resulting in more ops https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop

Comment: Sure, the raw loop might be faster. But in the context of the rest of the code, the loop body itself is doing so much work that it dwarfs the amount of work done by the loop control structure. If you got down into the microsecond range, the code using the `for ... in range` might be slightly faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the time complexity is correct, and I couldn't find any errors in your implementations, so my guess is that the reason is that `for ... in range` is faster than `while` loop in python.
(More information here [Why is looping over range() in Python faster than using a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop))

Edit:

The reason for this inconsistency between the comparison between time complexities and the comparison between actual running times of implementations, is that the time complexity regards only the amount of comparisons, while ignoring additional operations overhead (as it's `O(1)` for each comparison), but those additional operations and they way it's implemented (e.g. compiled vs. interpreted, cache friendliness) may significantly affect the running time.

Comment: wow! that's an interesting point, let me see if i can rewrite it as a for loop

Comment: hmmm, I have rewritten the function to perform a for loop, using a conditional check to break if we have sorted the current index back as far as it can go, and it looks like the timing has not really changed. but you bring up a good point, which is that O(n^2) refers to the amount of comparison we will perform, but it does not reflect the true amount of operations that will be performed, and so it serves as a generalization of time, not an accurate prediction. is that a good way of putting it?

Comment: Exactly, the time complexity analysis refers only to the number of comparisons, as other operations take constant time. this constant time does not affect the complexity but it can be significant in the actual running time.

Comment: if you can put that in your answer I will accept it as the answer

Comment: I Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea.

In Insertion sort, in the inner loop, you are replacing the items in the array with every loop. This creates a pseudo-bubble sort algorithm as far as implementation is concerned (number of read-write operations). Maybe you can hold your next number in position `i` in a variable, find it's suitable place in your sorted array, then move all the items.

Also, when compared with your selection sort, the number of accesses you make to the array is much more higher. In selection sort, you only do 2 accesses to array in the inner loop and the indexes don't change unless there is a new minimum number so python caches it. In insertion sort, you make 6 accesses to array in the inner loop, your index changes with every iteration and all your accesses to the array are dependent to `index` variable so python can't cache it. When you add the above mentioned read-write operations to it, it becomes slower.

Comment: haven't gotten around to reading this yet, curious why it was downvoted

Comment: The first part of your answer is good. The last paragraph is ... a little wonky. I know that in Python `arr[-1]` returns the last element of the array, but that's not true in other languages. In other languages, that would access memory before the beginning of the array, potentially leading to an unauthorized access exception. You probably should mention that the optimization is Python specific and explain what it does, in case somebody tries to port the code to some other language.

Comment: @JimMischel you are right. I think I will remove that part as it creates confusiın and does not add a value to the asked problem.

Answer (score 1):

The insertion sort implementation, while technically correct, is suboptimal.

- It does 3 assignments, and
- It tests two conditions (`index > 0` and `arr[index - 1] > arr[index]`)

on each iteration of the inner loop. You can get away with one assignment, and one test. To remove unnecessary assignments, consider

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        index = i
        scratch = arr[i]
        while index > 0 and arr[index - 1] > arr[index]:
            arr[index] = arr[index - 1]
            index -= 1
        arr[index] = scratch
    return arr
```

To decrease the number of tests, consider

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        scratch = arr[i]
        if scratch < arr[0]:
            # Don't bother about the values; just shift the array
            for index in range(i, 0, -1):
                arr[index] = arr[index - 1]
            arr[0] = scratch
        else:
            index = i
            # Don't bother about indices: the loop is naturally guarded by arr[0]
            while arr[index - 1] > arr[index]:
                arr[index] = arr[index - 1]
                index -= 1
            arr[index] = scratch
    return arr
```

---

There are few problems with timing the algorithms.

First, for a fair comparison you should time them against the same data. When timing an average case, each algorithm gets its own sets of shuffled arrays.

Second, `total` is accumulated over runs of different sizes. This gives an unfair advantage to an algorithm which performs better on shorter datasets.

---

Nitpick: a pythonic way to swap `arr[i]` with `arr[min_index]` (selection sort) is

```
    arr[i], arr[min_index] = arr[min_index], arr[i]
```

Comment: haven't gotten around to reading this yet, curious why it was downvoted

Comment: Good advice on the insertion sort algorithm. Not sure why it was downvoted.