# Using conditional statements in while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I was under the impression that adding the following if statement in my while loop makes python pick only the odd values of i that are smaller than 7 and sums them. However, this is not the case.

Here's my code:

```
i = 0

sum = 0

while i < 7:

    if (i % 2) == 1:

        sum += i

        i += 1
```

I expect sum to be 9 but an infinite loop occurs, causing the sum to be infinite.

I can't seem to understand how. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only increment `i` inside the `if`, so if the condition is not meant, `i` stays the same forever

Answer (score 1):

You only increment `i` inside the `if`, so if the condition is not meant, `i` stays the same forever

```py
i = 0

sum = 0

while i < 7:

    if (i % 2) == 1:

        sum += i

    i += 1

print(sum)
```

Output:

> 9

Answer (score 0):

As you keep conditioning `i % 2`, but if it doesn't go through, the `i` never changes, it will always exit the `if` statement, to solve it:

```
i = 0

sum = 0

while i < 7:

    if (i % 2) == 1:

        sum += i

    i += 1

print(sum)
```

You have to unindent by 4 spaces your `i += 1` line.

Answer (score 0):

For similar cases it is better to use for loop than while loop. Especially if you have long loops. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop)

```py
sum = 0
for i in range(7):
    if (i % 2) == 1:
        sum += i
```