# Efficient way to threshold image array and render - Python / NumPy / OpenCV

Tags: python, arrays, performance, loops, numpy

I have a camera that is sending the image data to my computer. From there my python script puts the 8bit color info (black and white; ranging from 0 - black - to 255 - white) into a numpy array. The array is 2D, first dimension up to 384 and second dimensions up to 288
Displaying this with a openCV window works great and the live video is more than 24fps.

My aim now is to manipulate the image, so that the live video displays any color value below 200 as 0 (completely black) and any color value above 200 as 255 (completely white). However, my code right now only gives me about 3fps.

My code is doing the following:

- save the image that comes from the camera in a numpy array
- open the first `for` loop to iterate through the x values
- in that first `for` loop iterate through the second `for` loop with the y values
- check each color value for every pixel and check if it is above 200 or not
- depending on the `if` clause make the color value 0 or 255
- display the new image

This is the decisive part in the code:

```
processedImage = frame
i = 0
for i in range(0, displayedWidth):
    ii = 0
    for ii in range(0, displayedHeight):
        if frame[ii, i] > 200:
            processedImage[ii, i] = 255
        else: 
            processedImage[ii, i] = 0
cv2.imshow("LiveVideo", processedImage)
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop) that `for` loops are faster than `while` loops, but it didn't improve the code's speed significantly, which is why I assume the rewriting of the `processedImage` takes too long.

Is there a way to make the whole process faster?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```py
frame[frame > 200] = 255
frame[frame <= 200] = 0
cv2.imshow("LiveVideo", frame)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This made it go back to more than 24fps and the video is running smooth again. Will mark it as correct asap.

Answer (score 1):

`np.where()` can be used too:

```py
processed_frame = np.where(frame >= 200, 255, 0)
```

---

e.g.

```py
>>> im = (np.random.rand(5, 5) * 255).round()
>>> im
array([[ 45.,  92.,  74., 207., 211.],
       [206., 184.,  31., 117., 119.],
       [ 88.,  82., 203.,  34.,   5.],
       [157.,  99., 154., 251.,  54.],
       [160., 177.,  14., 206., 234.]])
>>> np.where(im >= 200, 255, 0)
array([[  0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, 255, 255]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Staying with NumPy, it seems fastest would be -

```
(frame>200)*np.uint8(255)
```

Since, you are already using OpenCV, a faster way would be with `cv2.threshold` -

```
cv2.threshold(frame,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Sample run to verify results and get timings on `1024X1024` image -

```
In [2]: np.random.seed(0)
   ...: frame = np.random.randint(0,256,(1024,1024)).astype(np.uint8)

In [3]: %timeit (frame>200)*np.uint8(255)
253 µs ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit cv2.threshold(frame,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
58.2 µs ± 437 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)    

In [7]: out1 = (frame>200)*np.uint8(255)

In [8]: out2 = cv2.threshold(frame,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

In [9]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[9]: True
```

Timings with other solutions on same data -

```
# @AKX's soln
In [10]: %timeit np.where(frame >= 200, 255, 0)
3.73 ms ± 22.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @Seb's soln
In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: frame[frame > 200] = 255
    ...: frame[frame <= 200] = 0
10.2 ms ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

OpenCV's version with `cv2.threshold` seems the fastest by a big margin among others.

Answer (score 0):

Using Seb's solution is a big improvement but it seems that using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is even faster:

```
%%timeit
frame1 = frame.copy()
frame1[frame1 > 200] = 255
frame1[frame1 <= 200] = 0

974 µs ± 19.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

vs.

```
%%timeit
frame2 = frame.copy()
frame2 = np.where(frame2 > 200, 255, 0)

385 µs ± 7.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
>>> np.alltrue(frame1 == frame2)
True
```

Comment: When I try your or @AKX solution I get the error `(-215: Assertion failed)` when trying to display the image with `cv2.imshow(...)`. 
Would I be able to save the points where the color value is above 200 with this as well, or would I need a second `np.where()` statement?

Comment: Yes, the result should be the same as Seb's approach. For reference, I tested it with this array: `frame = np.floor(256 * np.random.rand(384, 288)).astype(int)`